# How to generate a periodic, unpredictable, verifiable random number?

Tags: random, cryptography, random-seed

I would like a random number for a program with the following qualities:

1. Periodic: The random number needs to be random for a certain window of time. Preferably hourly but could be more. Once the period is over, the next random number can be generated and previously generated values can be regenerated based on seed values which are publicly available.
2. Unpredictable: The next random number cannot be easily determined. The publicly available seed must not be public yet.
3. Verifiable: The seed for the random number should come from some publicly available source. Perhaps a scientific research organization or government body is publishing a daily or hourly number(s). For example, a group of temperatures that are recorded. Or for example, it could be as simple as a website that publishes hourly or daily random numbers.
4. Seed should be at least a 64 bit integer. If it's too small then the random number could be guessed from a small set.
5. Industrial-strength or exacting randomness is not required. Not interested in extreme, high-precision randomness.

I see https://avkg.com/ generates large, daily random numbers and this is actually very close and if nothing else looks better I will probably use it. Especially since it archives past results and so that satisfies the verifiable requirement. The problem is the site does not have a clean and documented API and it's not hourly. HTML scraping for this information is not ideal.

Another idea I had was to use a hash of a specific group of people's latest Tweets (X). Doing something like this would allow for verification. The problem is I don't know if they will tweet daily or hourly. Also, Elon has now made Twitter (X) non-public so you need to sign in to gather this information.

Another idea is to just create a my own version of AVKG.

Of course, a date will not work since that does not satisfy the above unpredictable requirement.

Any ideas?

Thank you so much.

Comment: So you will eventually publish the seed after using it to generate random numbers? Is periodicity a requirement or merely not disqualifying?

Comment: Yes. The world would know the seed at the moment the period begins, but not before.

Comment: and for the second question: Yes. Periodicity is a requirement. The purpose of the application is to generate a periodic random number, whose past values can be verified to be random.

Answer (score 2):

Given what you've written I think I'd just use a symmetric cipher (e.g. ChaCha20) in counter mode to generate requested data, and a KDF (e.g. Argon2) for transitioning between keys.

Your private state would be:

- `key` the private key used for this period
- `salt` the salt used to transition to this key

Your public state would be:

- `ctr` the current counter value
- `log` previously used private keys and salts

When somebody makes a request, you'd atomically:

1. use the `key` and `ctr` to produce a new block of random data, `data`
2. respond with `i = len(log)`, `ctr`, `data`
3. increment `ctr`

When you move into the next period, you'd atomically:

1. append `key` and `salt` to `log`
2. reset `ctr` to zero
3. generate 16 random bytes in `salt`
4. generate a new `key` using the KDF to mix this `salt` with the previous period's `key`

When users want to verify their `data`, they'd:

1. request the public state
2. verify that the key from `log[i]` and `ctr` produce their `data`

If users want to verify their `key` was generated securely, they'd:

1. request public state
2. verify that combining the `key` from `log[i-1]` with the `salt` in `log[i]` produces the `key` in `log[i]`

Users could anonymously (e.g. from multiple unrelated hosts) request the public state to verify:

- that these don't change unexpectedly
- when performing a request for data that these are consistent

Comment: you might want to allow users to pass some state along with the request and incorporate this when generating `data`.  that way you have some confidence that the server wouldn't be able to significantly affect the random values returned as they wouldn't have complete control over cipher state

Comment: Thank you, Sam. The question I have regarding your solution is how would the public know the key was generated in a "cryptographically secure manner?" Seems this is not really verifiably random?

Comment: good point! have defined some key transition function.  you'd want to pick a reasonable KDF such that users would know it couldn't be exhaustively evaluated over even a small proportion (e.g. 2^-64) of the key space between periods

Comment: Thanks, Sam. Please correct me if I am wrong, but the "generation" of the "16 random bytes in salt" is server-side? In that case, how could the anonymous user check the public state to verify it was actually randomly chosen instead of made up to suit the server owner's needs?

Comment: Because it's being passed through a KDF in a way that can be checked.  Basically KDFs, like hashes, are one way functions.  I.e. it's easy to go one way, but it's computationally infeasible to go back.  So unless the attacker had perfect knowledge of every time users would request state they couldn't predict the output.  If you allowed users to pass some state in (like in my first comment) then even that's avoided